# Выравнивание текста в DataGridTextColumn по вертикали. Границы ячейки начинают выравниваться вокруг текста

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю выравнивание текста в DataGridTextColumn по вертикали

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Header="..."
                    SortDirection="Ascending">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

В результате границы ячейки тоже мигрируют на середину 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Как сделать так, чтобы границы ячейки не рисовались по центру ячейки?

Comment: Дополнил немного ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, стандартный шаблон ячейки таков, что стилем это поведение не исправить, придется изменять шаблон (благо хотя бы там изменения будут простыми), для этого кликните в дизайнере правой кнопкой по DataGrid и выберите <kbd>Edit Additional Templates</kbd>-<kbd>Edit CellStyle</kbd>-<kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd>

В добавившийся стандартный стиль в шаблоне (`<Setter Property="Template">`) найдите `ContentPresenter` представляющий содержимое ячейки и установите ему `VerticalAlignment="Center"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотите иметь возможность настраивать выравнивание по разному в разных столбцах, то можно вместо явного указания значения выполнить привязку: `VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"`, тогда в столбце делаем так:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Это более предпочтительный и универсальный метод.